# lombok @AllArgsConstructor vs defining my own constructor using Objects.requireNonNull()

Tags: java-7, lombok

I have been using lombok's `@AllArgsConstructor` annotation in my code to keep code clean. But i just noticed that my colleague defined their own constructor with Java7's  `Objects.requireNonNull()` with the arguments passed into the constructor.

Can anyone tell me what are the advantages ( if any ) or disadvantages of doing so ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `@AllArgsConstructor` will by default not create any `null` checks. You can add those by annotating the fields you want to be non-`null` with `@NonNull` as stated [here](https://projectlombok.org/features/NonNull).

So in my opinion there is no benefit to creating your own constructor other than that you are able to customize the message of the exception that is thrown, which is not possible using `ProjectLombok` (but do you need it?) Lombok's message is just the name of the field that is `null`.

Comment: thanks, i guess that makes sense. I was trying to see if there's any "strong" reasons not to use Lombok. Guess i will stick with lombok for now.